# Find cosines of angles between $(1,0,-1)$ and the unit coordinate vectors; check that $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> What are the cosines of the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ between the vector $(1,0,-1 )$ and the unit vectors $i$, $j$, and $k$ along the axes? Check the formula  $$\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1$$

What exactly is this question? I am lost and feel like it lacks context. The statement regarding the squares of Cosines ... where did that come from? Certainly, the chapter that this question belongs to has no context.

I am aware of the cosine formula for a given set of unit vectors and their dot product, and I am aware of the formula for sine in the context of cross product of a set of vectors (as long as they are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^7$).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The identity involving direction cosines is
$$\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are the angles that the vector makes with the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes, respectively.  If you have learned about projection and the dot product, then you should be able to derive this identity.

A vector $\overrightarrow{u}=(a,b,c)$ can be written in terms of its direction cosines:
$$\overrightarrow{u}=(a,b,c)=(\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma)=\bigg(\frac{a}{|\overrightarrow{u}|},\frac{b}{|\overrightarrow{u}|},\frac{c}{|\overrightarrow{u}|}\bigg).$$

The vector $(1,0,-1)$ therefore makes angles of $45^{\circ}$, $90^{\circ}$, and $135^{\circ}$ with the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes, respectively.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, Andrew.